# Filtering what strategy to use in strategy pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a situation where I've used the strategy pattern but got many different strategies that are available to the client code that needs to select the appropriate strategy, this is because there's a lot of different usages to the strategy depending on the machine that's being calculated, because of the domain it's being used in.

My question is specifically about the filter part of the code, the part where a relevant strategy is picked, I decide to filter first on the location, then the main category of the machine object and then the MachineName (an enum). These can all influence what kind of calculation can be done.

A machine object looks like this (other parts removed for brevity):

```
public class Machine() { 
  public Category MainCategory   { get; set; } 
  public MachineName MachineName { get; set; }
  public Location MachineLocation {get; set; }
}
```

My filter code for the client part looks like this, note that there are around 30-35 options in total based on either the MachineName or the machine location (first in line for example).

```
public void BasicFilter(Machine Current_Machine) 
{
  if(Current_Machine.MachineLocation == 1) { _strategyService.SetStrategy(new FirstMachineStrategy);}
  else if ( Current_Machine.MainCategory == MainCategory.Producer) 
  {
    switch (Current_Machine.MachineName)
            {
                case MachineName.MultiRoller:
                  _strategyService.SetStrategy(new MultiRollerStrategy);
                // Other options removed for brevity
                default:
                 _strategyService.SetStrategy(new RollerStrategy);
            }
  }
  else if ( Current_Machine.MainCategory == MainCategory.Reciever)
  {
    _strategyService.SetStrategy(new RecieverStrategy);
  }
}
```

For completeness sake; I've also added a strategy as an example, again this differs on the location, name, or category. Where the strategy below is one of the default one(s)

```
public class RollerStrategy : ICalculationStrategy
{
    public object CalculateSteelValues(Machine Current_Machine, Machine Last_Machine)
    {
        Current_Machine.SteelAmount = Last_Machine.SteelAmount;

        if (Current_Machine.Reduction == 0)
        {
            // Can't divide through 0. So do nothing
        } else
        {
            Current_Machine.SteelThickness = Last_Machine.SteelThickness / Current_Machine.Reduction;
            Current_Machine.SteelWidth = Last_Machine.SteelWidth + Last_Machine.SteelThickness - Current_Machine.SteelThickness;
        }

        return Current_Machine;
    }
```

Is there a better implementation for filtering the different strategies, or something that would be cleaner to maintain, I didn't use a singular switch case statement on the name because I thought it would clutter and I'd need to find another solution for the location(s).

I've just recently started to use this pattern, so I was wondering if I was missing something.

EDIT:

The machine enums are nothing more than it's the exact name; here's a sample of the Enum's used:

```
    public enum MachineName
    {
         MultiRoller,
         TwoRoller,
         // Etc
    }

    public enum Category
    {
      Blank,
      Roller,
      Infeed,
    }

    public enum Location
    {
      Blank,
      FirstInLine,
      LastInLine,
    }
```

Comment: Do not prefix your variable names with the class name. `machine.Name` is plenty clear, `machine.MachineName` is overkill. Also, `MachineName` doesn't seem to be a name but a type.

Comment: I'm confused. In the text you are saying *filter first on the main category, then the machine name and if needed the location* then in your code the first line examines the location. Could you please sync your code and the text?

Comment: Please also share with us the definitions of the enums.

Comment: Code reviews are different from debugging, the more code you provide the better the review we can do. A statement in the question such as `A machine object looks like this (other parts removed for brevity):` means that we really can't do a good code review and that perhaps you aren't really looking for a code review.

Comment: Providing the entire Machine object is of no issue; I just thought that it wasn't relevant for this particular part of code hence why I indeed removed it